# How to set an Environmental Variable using .bat file

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I tried this code in a notepad and save it as **path.bat**
When I double click on the batch file, it won't set the Variable... Can anyone show me the error with my code or provide me the best solution?

```
@echo off
title This is your first batch script!
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Users\Core i3\Desktop\New folder (2)\jdk1.7.0_71"
setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
exit
```

Comment: Type `setx /?` at a command prompt and read the section named NOTE:, particularly items #2 and #3.

Comment: I don't understand what you just said. can you be little more specific? @KenWhite

Comment: I said *Open a command window. Type `setx /?` and hit ENTER. Read what  appears on the screen, especially the section that starts with *NOTE*, and pay close attention to what is written in items numbered 2 and 3. I don't know how to be more specific than that without coming to sit at your desk and do everything for you. :-)

Comment: It says

"'setx' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

@KenWhite

Comment: @CodeBae - are you using `windows xp` ?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the [`set` command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)?

Comment: No I'm using Windows 10 @npocmaka

Comment: @aschipfl: no, not set command. I'm looking for the command to right in the batch file.

Comment: @CodeBae  not sure if `setx -m` requires admin permissions.

Comment: I need to write a new Environmental variable (that is the *bin* path of *JDK*)
So I need to write the `command` into a batch file

Comment: You seem to have messed around with the `PATH` variable; otherwise, the error message `'setx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` should not appear. You may also try to specify the full path of `setx`: `"%SystemRoot%\System32\setx.exe"`...

Comment: If `setx` is not recognized, you've already borked your PATH.

Answer (score 1):

`setx` does not set the variable for the current session, it sets it for `cmd` instances created in the future.

Comment: The code sample appears to work quite satisfactorally. What help do you need? Possibly add a line `pause` before the `exit`. That should tell you what the result of running the batch is. There's little point in setting `title` as it stands, since all it will do is set the variables for future `cmd` instances and then close.

Comment: I think, the Command Line is not executed by Administrative privileges (Run as Administrator)...
How can I achieve that?

Comment: However, `path` is a variable that specifies the sequence of directories that are examined for an executable. Since when you run the file, `java_home` is not established (it's only set for **future** `cmd` instances) then you'll add `;\bin` to your existing `path`. If `setx` is not found, then it *should* be in `c:\windows\system32` or `c:\windows\syswow64` - and one or both of these should be in your current `path`.

Comment: Can you provide me with the code please?  I'm new to batch file System and I'm a beginner...

Comment: Well - first thing - DON'T. You need to first take a copy of your current `path` so that if you damage it you can restore it. From the command prompt, execute `set>somefilename.txt` to record your current environment in a file. You can then use `notepad` or an editor to examine the file. To run using administrative privileges, right-click on the object and select "run as administrator"

Comment: FIRST STEP: Go to Programs>System Tools>right-click on "Command Prompt" and "Send To Desktop". This will give you a "Command Prompt" facility (commonly, though technically incorrectly, called "DOS")

Comment: Non of these answers help me with the matter. BTW, thanks for your time.

Comment: You've probably overwritten the value of `path` in your environment. This is critical. I rarely venture into this area, and it's taken a long time for me to be sure of where in the registry the history is held. If you don't know what your `path` should be and you've deleted its value, you may need to do a system restore if you can't find the correct value in the registry. But maybe your `path` is fine. I can't tell from here.